# Javascript multi animation sheet

Tags: javascript, animation

I wrote my code using the following javascript library, [SimpleGame.js](http://aharrisbooks.net/h5g/simpleGame_1_0.js) by A. Harris.

My code follows, the problem is that the character does not animate while the arrow keys are *pressed*, it does animate when same keys are *released* ... what am I missing? Furthermore, key 39, which should be the left arrow key, does not work at all. Any help appreciated, Thank you.

http://www.retroinvaders.net/multiAnimationTest.html

Multi Animation Test

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="simpleGame.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var game;
    var background;
    var character;
    var critter;

    window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);


    function init() {
        game = new Scene();
        background = new Sprite(game, "media/rpgMap.png", 800, 600);
        background.setSpeed(0, 0);
        background.setPosition(400, 300);

        character = new Character();
        critter = new Critter();
        game.start();
    }

    function update() {
        game.clear();
        checkCollisions();
        background.update();
        character.update();
        critter.update();
    }

    function Character() {
        tCharacter = new Sprite(game, "media/rpg_sprite_walk.png", 192, 128);

        tCharacter.loadAnimation(192, 128, 24, 32);
        tCharacter.generateAnimationCycles();
        tCharacter.renameCycles(new Array("down", "up", "left", "right"));
        tCharacter.setAnimationSpeed(1000);

        tCharacter.setPosition(440, 380);
        tCharacter.setSpeed(0);
        tCharacter.pauseAnimation();
        tCharacter.setCurrentCycle("down");

        return tCharacter;
    }

    function keydownHandler(event) {

        if (event.keyCode === 37) {

            character.playAnimation();
            character.setCurrentCycle("left");
            character.setMoveAngle(270);
            character.changeXBy(-5);

        }

        if (event.keyCode === 39) {

            character.changeXby(5);

            character.playAnimation()
            character.setMoveAngle(90);
            character.setCurrentCycle("right");
        }

        if (event.keyCode === 38) {

            character.playAnimation()
            character.changeYby(-5);


            character.setMoveAngle(0);
            character.setCurrentCycle("up");
        }

        if (event.keyCode === 40) {

            character.changeYby(5);
            character.playAnimation()

            character.setMoveAngle(180);
            character.setCurrentCycle("down");
        }
    }



    function Critter() {
        tCritter = new Sprite(game, "media/critter.gif", 30, 30);
        tCritter.setSpeed(0);
        tCritter.setPosition(200, 200);
        return tCritter;
    }

    function checkCollisions() {
        if (character.distanceTo(critter) <= 30) {
            critter.hide();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: No problem with animation in FF. But for the left move, there is a typo : change `character.changeXBy(-5)` (l66) with `character.changeXby(-5)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo, I just corrected it. Yet the non working animation IS still a problem to me... any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were assigning new animationCycle each time you pressed a key.
It seems that chrome had no time to set the new animation cycles.
Use a flag to change only when needed fix this :

```
function keydownHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        if (character.animation.currentCycleName !== "left") {
            character.setCurrentCycle("left");
        }
        character.changeXby(-5);
        character.playAnimation();
        character.setMoveAngle(270);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        if (character.animation.currentCycleName !== "right") {
            character.setCurrentCycle("right");
        }
        character.changeXby(5);
        character.playAnimation()
        character.setMoveAngle(90);

    }

    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        if (character.animation.currentCycleName !== "up") {
            character.setCurrentCycle("up");
        }
        character.changeYby(-5);
        character.playAnimation();
        character.setMoveAngle(0);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
        if (character.animation.currentCycleName !== "down") {
            character.setCurrentCycle("down");
        }
        character.changeYby(5);
        character.playAnimation();
        character.setMoveAngle(180);

    }
}
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ww3oq1e9/4/)

Comment: This way it works just fine, than you so much. Although, I would like the character to actually **stop** moving when keys are released ... And I don't understand why is the semicolon after character.playAnymation() not necessary. Isn't this a method, just like _character.changeXby(5)..._? If you could answer or comment on this, too, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @raenset Sure, just add `window.addEventListener("keyup", function(){character.pauseAnimation();}, false);` see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww3oq1e9/4/)  and semicolons were typos

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! (I am sorry that I can't vote you at this time.) I don't understand about semicolons... do we need them or not? Why? And then, why isn't there a JavaScript error about them?

Comment: Thank you so much again!! Perhaps you can help with my only other question, too, for the time being, it's about tile-based collision detection...

Comment: I did the jsfiddle, and posted it as a comment on the other question of mine...and it should also be considered as an update to same question, removing unnecessary code. if you can help me, that would be much appreciated, thank you again.

Comment: Done. My apologies but I am a newbie in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Main problem in this case is collision detection with "tile", independent from particular case but dependent from tile state, rather than ordinary collision with other sprite. SimpleGame.js is beginner's library so I trust you won't have problems with that. Thank you so much again for your time and effort.